# How does NumPy compute the inverse of a matrix?

Tags: python, numpy, linear-algebra

Given a square matrix `A` as a [NumPy](https://numpy.org) array, like

```py
import numpy as np

A = np.array(
     [
         [1, 2, 3],
         [3, 4, 6],
         [7, 8, 9],
    ]
)
```

which algorithm does NumPy's [`linalg.inv`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.inv.html) use internally when

```
np.linalg.inv(A)
```

is invoked to compute the matrix inverse of `A`?

Particularly, as matrix inversion may be numerically unstable (depending on the [condition number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condition_number) of the matrix), are there any special cases considered depending on certain matrix properties?

Comment: It uses LU decomposition as stated in https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/22105/complexity-of-matrix-inversion-in-numpy

Comment: @projjal: Thanks for you comment! Would you mind making it an answer to that question so that I can accept it to make it easier for other readers?

Comment: Thank you I was looking at the source from the link and found the comment part. Glad you asked the question. I also got to know about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably note that, buried deep inside the numpy source code (see https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/linalg/umath_linalg.c.src) the inv routine attempts to call the dgetrf function from your system LAPACK package, which then performs an LU decomposition of your original matrix.

You can look at the comment in the code at line no 1036 which states:

```html
/* As in the linalg package, the determinant is computed via LU factorization
 * using LAPACK.
 * slogdet computes sign + log(determinant).
 * det computes sign * exp(slogdet).
 */
/**begin repeat
   #TYPE = FLOAT, DOUBLE, CFLOAT, CDOUBLE#
   #typ = npy_float, npy_double, npy_cfloat, npy_cdouble#
   #basetyp = npy_float, npy_double, npy_float, npy_double#
   #cblas_type = s, d, c, z#
*/
```

Thus and as @Yacola demonstrated that results of numpy inverse on matrix and LU decomposition are the same. This again proves the fact.

Answer (score 1):

Following @projjal 's comment, all of these are equivalent to compute the inverse of a square matrix:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.linalg import lu_factor, lu_solve

A = np.array([[1, 2, 3],[3, 4, 6],[7, 8, 9]])

A_inv_1 = np.linalg.inv(A)

A_inv_2 = np.linalg.solve(A,np.eye(A.shape[0]))

A_LU = lu_factor(A) # this way, you can potentially reuse the factorization for different RHS
A_inv_3 = lu_solve(A_LU,np.eye(A.shape[0]))

# check
np.allclose(A_inv_1,A_inv_2)
>>> True
np.allclose(A_inv_1,A_inv_3)
>>> True
```